# How to find all edges associated with a particular vertex?

Tags: graph-databases, titan, gremlin

I'd like to find all incoming and outgoing edges associated with any particular vertex(node) in Titan using Gremlin.

I issued below query and found the vertex - v[1443700]

```
gremlin> g.V('ip_address','192.168.1.1')
==>v[1443700]
```

Now I want to find all edges(relations) associated with `v[1443700]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [bothE()](http://gremlindocs.com/#transform/bothe) step -- either on its own or by including a label like `bothE('SOMELABEL')`

If you only want incoming edges use `inE()`, and if you only want outgoing edges use `outE()`.

```
g.V('ip_address','192.168.1.1').bothE()
```

You can find more information on steps at [gremlindocs.com](http://gremlindocs.com).